# Transform spaces in dots

Tags: css, spaces

Is there some css trick to allow me to transform whitespace characters like:

```
{[SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]function(){} }
```

into something like this:

```
{. . . . function(){}
```

The point is to display invisible characters in code blocks.

However it should not wrap the spaces in some elements, or use background-images or something like that.

Comment: Are you trying to preserve spaces when displaying the page, or actually transforming spaces into dots?

Comment: Make sure what you want? in CSS or javascript.

Comment: He wants invisible characters displayed, that's it.

Comment: I have a div with the white-space property set to **pre**, i know that are possible to adding content whit pseudo selectors like :after and :before.. for example if i want a text before a link i can do 'a.link:before{ content: 'MYLINK' }'.. I would to know if maybe are possible to make the same thing whit a space, maybe some unknowed selector..

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Exactly!! In poor words :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, consecutive whitespace characters collapse to a single space in HTML. So you would need to use `pre` or something equivalent to see several consecutive spaces in the first place.

CSS isn’t really supposed to make characters displayed as something different from what they are. But technically, you could edit a font so that it contains some graphic character in the slot for space, and use that font via `@font-face'.

But it would be much more sensible to replace the spaces by visible characters, either server-side or client-side.